# url redirections not working for anonymous users - redirecting to homepage

Tags: 8, redirection, event-subscribers

I have set a redirect rule in `EventSubscriber`. So according to rule, when I hit [example.com/my-page][1] in browser, it should redirect to [example.com/success][1] or some external url also.

**But issue is(for anonymous user):**

On hitting first time this url "[example.com/my-page][1]", **REDIRECT SUCCESS!!**
But on second time it does not redirect. It remains "[example.com/my-page][1]" only.

Now If I logged in, flush all cache, then again log out and check "example.com/my-page", it again works -- REDIRECT SUCCESS!!
But again after redirecting first time when accessed the same, it stops redirecting.

Comment: What code listens for the event? Why is _url_redirect a static function?

Comment: Kevin If I write `$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);` in event itself, then it redirects to homepage. Calling response inside event not allow redirection for authenticated users even.